# Forced-alignment in CUDA?

Tags: c, cuda, alignment, nvidia

Is there a way to create a 2D array a[][] where each of the a[i] itself is forced to align to some other data type in CUDA?

I want to do something like this:

```
__shared__ unsigned char a[20][8];// where a[i] is aligned to 8-byte boundary;

double t=*((double *)(a[2]));
```

Or even something like:

```
__shared__ unsigned char a[20][9];// where a[i] is aligned to 8-byte boundary;

double t=*((double *)(a[2]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of the code snippets you have shown are illegal in CUDA.

All current hardware requires alignment of types to word sized boundaries. In your example only reads from `a[0]`, `a[8]`, `a[16]`, etc would be valid because the hardware requires that any `double` read occur at from an 8 byte aligned boundary. Anything else will produce a run time error from the device. Even if you try using a structure, the compiler will enforce the alignment by padding. If you want a different, *valid* alignment, the language supports an [__align__ specifier](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory-accesses) for structures.

Which is a long winded way of saying no.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a union?

```
union my_union_type {
    char   a[8];
    double t;
};

my_union_type var[20];

char   a = var.a[2][3];
double t = var.t[2];
```

This is not equivalent to your second example because (as talonmies has pointed out) your example is illegal and would generate invalid code, while my code would insert the correct alignment of 7 bytes after each element. But I think it comes closest to what you are asking for.